# #define ^ in c++ is not allowed

Tags: c++, preprocessor

I am not able to give seperate meaning to `^` using `#define`, like `#define ^ +`.
But where as I am able to give meaning to `$` using `#define` , like `#define $ +`.

Could you please let me know how `$` is different from `^`?
On which rule of c++ standard this `^` is not allowed?

I am using VC++ 2012, Not tried with GCC or any other tool.

Comment: `^` is bitwise xor already whereas `$` is.. nothing. do operator overloading with `^` if you want to give it special meaning

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369495/what-are-the-valid-characters-for-macro-names

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884985/will-using-a-preprocessor-directive-to-define-what-a-dollar-sign-represents-caus

Answer (score 4):

`^` is an operator in C++. It is a bitwise XOR. Please read https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_operators.htm

Operators cannot be "redefined" in this way, you need to overload them. C++ allows you to specify more than one definition for a function name or an operator in the same scope, which is called function overloading and operator overloading respectively (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm
and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Operators/Operator_Overloading#Bitwise_operators)

For bitwise operators, generally, they have a lower precedence than the arithmetic operators, so if ^ were to be overloaded for exponentiation, x ^ y + z may not work as expected.

For XOR  the canonical form is: `Type operator^(const Type &lhs, const Type &rhs); // Bitwise exclusive or`, while for member function versions: `Type &operator^=(const Type &rhs); // Assign exclusive or`.

reference: http://articles.emptycrate.com/2009/10/12/nobody_understands_c_part_8_operator_overloading.html

Comment: If ^ is an operator and this is the reason for this failure, then the same should happen for +,=,* and /. But all the following are valid, no compilation error. #define + -, #define * -  etc.

Comment: If you really have a C preprocessor which lets you `#define` operator symbols, then you are definitely well distant from standard C++

Answer (score 3):

The rules for names of preprocessor macros are the same as for identifiers:  they can contain uppercase and lowercase letters, underscores, and numeric digits only.   The first character in an identifier cannot be a digit.

That means it is not possible to use `#define` to redefine the meaning of operators like `^`.

In standard C++, this also excludes identifiers containing a `$`.   However, some compilers support identifiers containing `$` as an extension.

Comment: "In standard C++, this also excludes identifiers containing a $." is it mentioned in any part of the C++ specification?

Comment: @susanth: Sure. It's in section 2.10, where identifiers are defined as starting with a one 53 characters (upper and lower case ASCII letters, plus the `_` symbol) and continuing with more of the same, plus possibly the 10 ASCII digits. They may also include "universal-character-names", which are unicode characters encoded in hex signalled with `\u` or `\U`, but only letter-like characters are allowed, and the smallest valid code is `\u00A8`. (And the compiler may allow you to use the actual Unicode character.) 16.3 paragraph 10 says `#define` must be followed by an identifier.

Answer (score -2):

^ is an operator you can use it to get input of strings with space like this scanf ("%[^\n]s,&x)...So you can only overload it and not define it as it has already been defined

Comment: `^` is bitwise XOR. What does it have to do with `scanf`?

Comment: What ever is inside "..." should be ignored in preprocessing, right?